# Phenol or ethanol as a nucleophile for ether formation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, reactivity, ethers

If we react phenol with $\ce{C2H5I}$ in $\ce{C2H5O- Na+}$ (excess), $\ce{C2H5OH}$ (anhydrous) solutions .

In this reaction why is diethyl ether not formed and the actual product is phenyl ethyl ether? 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding excess sodium ethanolate so there is the possibility of deprotonation of phenol: $$\ce{C6H5OH + C2H5O- <=> C6H5O- + C2H5OH}$$

If we look at the $\text{p}K_\text{a}$ of ethanol and phenol we have 16 and 9.95 respectively and so the equilibrium above will strongly favour the right hand side. Therefore, the phenoxide ion will dominate as a nucleophile in the mixture, and the major product will be ethyl phenyl ether.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, until I saw that the EtO- is apparently "in excess"... Ethoxide is definitely more nucleophilic than phenoxide and if both are present I would not be surprised if lots of Et2O was formed.

Comment: @orthocresol Hmm. You are probably right.

Comment: So, you mean to say that phenoxide is _not_ a better nucleophile than ethoxide (on the basis of resonating structures), but only happens to be the dominant nucleophile in this case just because it is present in more amount than ethoxide?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yes that is what I am saying.